# hide modal without links bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap with modal popup when I click at my create button popup shows and I enter the data and click at save button the links are shown

[image]

when I click at edit then popup shows and popup is

[image]

but at popup click at cancel button the links `View HTML | Edit | Delete | PDF` has been gone. My cancel button is `<button type="button" class="btn default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>` and I found `data-dismiss="modal"` this attribute clear/remove/hide the links. Is there any other alternate to hide the popup without clear/remove/hide the links.

Links code

```
$("#appendDockReceipt").empty();
appendDockReceipt += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0);\" title=\"View HTML\" onclick=\"\">View HTML</a> | ";
appendDockReceipt += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0);\" title=\"Edit\" onclick=\"javascript: cleanScreen('dockReceiptClickEdit'); bookingAjaxFunc('"+url+"', '"+dockReceiptRow.bookingsLettersDockReceiptId+"', 'dockReceiptFetch');\" data-target=\"#createDockReceipt\" data-toggle=\"modal\">Edit</a> | ";
appendDockReceipt += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0);\" title=\"Delete\" onclick=\"deleteConfirmation('"+url+"', '"+dockReceiptRow.bookingsLettersDockReceiptId+"', 'dockReceiptDelete', 'bookingAjaxFunc');\">Delete</a> | ";
appendDockReceipt += "<a href=\"javascript: void(0);\" title=\"PDF\" onclick=\"bookingAjaxFunc('"+url+"', '"+dockReceiptRow.bookingsLettersDockReceiptId+"', 'createDockReceiptPDF');\">PDF</a>";
$("#appendDockReceipt").append(appendDockReceipt);
```

And popup div code is

```
<div id="createDockReceipt" class="modal fade" id="portlet-config" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
textfieds and buttons goes here
    </div>
```

And button which shows the popup

```
<a class=" btn red-intense" href="#"  data-target="#createDockReceipt" data-toggle="modal">Save</a>
```

Comment: Can you show some code? Expecially the top links.

Comment: We need more code than this to debug your issue.  Please include the 'relevant' JS, HTML bits

Comment: check the update. I append the code with jquery

Comment: you do know about  $("#modalID").modal('hide'), right?